# Why my neural network isn't able to classify correctly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I made a simple neural network to classify food into only two classes egg or meat, however every time i train the model, it gives me a constant result despite the image change, like if i train for first time it recognize every image as a meat and for the second time it recognize all the images as egg, i don't know if it's a mistake in my code.

Here where i read the data :

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names= None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
    )
```

Here is where i predict using `softmax` activate function after flattening the data :

```py
def forward(x):
    return tf.matmul(x,W) + b

def model(x):
    x = flatten(x)
    return activate(x)

def activate(x):
    return tf.nn.softmax(forward(x))
```

calculating the error using `cross_entropy`

```py
def cross_entropy(y_label, y_pred):
    return (-tf.reduce_sum(y_label * tf.math.log(y_pred + 1.e-10)))
```

modifying values using descent gradient :

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.25)

def train_step(x, y ):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            #compute loss function
            current_loss = cross_entropy( y, model(x))
            # compute gradient of loss 
            #(This is automatic! Even with specialized funcctions!)
            grads = tape.gradient( current_loss , [W,b] )
            # Apply SGD step to our Variables W and b
            optimizer.apply_gradients( zip( grads , [W,b] ) )     
        return current_loss.numpy()
```

and finally, training the model :

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([196608, 2],tf.float32))
# Bias tensor
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2],tf.float32))

loss_values=[]
accuracies = []
epochs = 100

for i in range(epochs):
    j=0
    # each batch has 50 examples
    for x_train_batch, y_train_batch in train_ds:
        
        j+=1
        current_loss = train_step(x_train_batch/255.0, tf.one_hot(y_train_batch,2))
        if j%500 == 0: #reporting intermittent batch statistics
            print("epoch ", str(i), "batch", str(j), "loss:", str(current_loss) ) 
 

   

Update:
I have discovered that the problem is in the gradients, they are always zero except for the first time
```

Comment: In the train_step function, where are you doing the forward pass through your network and getting the y_pred. y is an argument to the function but how are you calculating it? It seems to me you are not doing the forward pass correctly

Comment: I should note that this is not a neural network you have set up here, it's just a regressor since there is no hidden layer.

Comment: also initializing your W and b to zeroes is incorrect, unless tensorflow is fixing that on the back end by doing its own initialization, in which case it's not the problem, but still confusing.

Comment: I don't know, i am still learning and i was following a tutorial, all what i changed is the dataset, they use MNIST and i use as you see my own data

Comment: But i still think it's called a neural network , i think neural network is where i have a neuron hits the input by a  weight, and i indeed wanted to initialise the weights with a number instead of zeros but my lap freeze

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, are you actually going over the training data and using your training step, in the code you provided there is no training loop that goes over your `train_ds`, seems like your behavior is more down to initialization cos you don't actually train the model.

Comment: My mistake, i wrongly pasted the same function twice instead of the training code, i updated the question

Comment: @moumenShobakey Have to tried setting ```tf.GradientTape(persistent=True)``` as per [tf documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) it only computes the gradient once.

"Unless you set persistent=True a GradientTape can only be used to compute one set of gradients"

Comment: isn't it actually one set consisting of w and b?

Comment: Hey i discovered that gradients are indeed zero except for the first time, so i added persistent and still the same problem

Answer (score -1):

After days of debugging, i discovered that the grads are zero, i then found out why, this was because the softmax function, as the values of x_train were very large so it gives out zeros and ones, which makes the change tends to zero, to walk around i just divided the forward(x) arguments over a large number